# Why do we say functional API in Keras is used for non-sequential models?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

AFAIK, we still need to create a model and add layers to the model using the [functional API](https://keras.io/models/model/). Why people say that the functional AI is used to create non-sequential neural network?

Answer (score 12):

> Why people said it is used to non-sequential neural network?

The thing is that with the `Sequential Model` you are defining a model step by step (sequentially), when you call the `.add()` method. Whereas, on the Functional API (specifically the `Model` class) you have more freedom, as you can define different *layers* that receive different inputs and then *instantiate* a model with the `Model` creator using any of those layers (not necessarily in a step by step, or sequential way).

In other words, when calling `model = Sequential()` you are **in that moment instantiating your model object** (for which you then add layers and constraints). In the Functional API, **you create layers and then instantiate your model** by calling `model = Model(inputs=in, outputs=out)` with your desired input and output layer(s). As you see, both approaches can be equivalent, for example, these two are the same:

```py
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Activation
#---Using the Sequential model
model = Sequential() #Object is instantiated here
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=784))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
#---Or using the Functional API
a = Input(shape=(784,))
b = Dense(32, activation='relu')(a)
model = Model(inputs=a, outputs=b) #Object is instantiated here
```

Considering only this, then choosing which way to go depends more on your personal style and coding preferences. Now, there is a **major advantage** of using the Functional API over the Sequential model, which is that **you can share or reuse layers across different models**.

**When compiling and fitting a model, all its associated layers will be compiled and trained. Thus, any other model that shares such layers will also reflect those changes**. This gives you the freedom to do many things, as obtaining sub-models of your network, redefine them, obtain its relative outputs, merge them into more complex models, etc., without having to train again for each of those sub-models.

To make it clearer, here is an example (based on [this](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) Keras Autoencoder Blog post) that illustrates what was discussed in the last paragraph:

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
#Create an autoencoder, along with its encoder and decoder model
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
encoded = Dense(32, activation='relu')(input_img)
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

#Here we define our autoencoder model: image -> encoding -> decoded image
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)

#Now here is the advantage of the Funcional API
#We can reuse those layers to obtain an encoder model (image -> encoding)
#as well as a decoder model (encoding -> image)
#but compile all three by just compiling and fitting the Autoencoder model
encoder = Model(input_img, encoded) #see how the 'encoded' layer is output
# create a placeholder for an encoded (32-dimensional) input
encoded_input = Input(shape=(32,))
# retrieve the last layer of the autoencoder model
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
# create the decoder model
decoder = Model(encoded_input, decoder_layer(encoded_input))
#compile and fit with your data
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
autoencoder.fit(X,Y,...)
```

After this, you will be able to make predictions on the `encoder` and `decoder` model individually (to visualize your encoding, for example), as well as make predictions with the `autoencoder` model as a whole. At this point, doing the following things are equivalent:

```py
#obtain reconstructed representation directly
autoencoder_imgs = autoencoder.predict(x_test)
#obtain reconstructed representation by joining encoder and decoder models
encoder_imgs = encoder.predict(x_test)
decoded_imgs = decoder.predict(encoded_imgs)
```

Hope this helps. Personally, I always try to use the Functional API instead, regardless if I want or not to reuse or recycle layers, as *I* find it more verbose, but that is up to you to decide.

Comment: Another major advantage of the functional API is creating models with as many ramifictaions as you like. You're not obliged to follow a straight line like in the sequential model.

Comment: By the way, it's possible to make autoencoders with Sequential models. Encoder being one sequential, decoder being anoter sequential, and autoencoder a sequential that gets the other two added.

Comment: @DanielMöller yes you can, but illustrated with that example to make it clearer. And yes :) you can ramificate your model as desired, by *reusing* your layers. Like, say, a base model trained and then reused and extended to n different new models (taking advantage of the fact you already trained the shared model, or just make use of that sharing).

Answer (score 6):

Well, "sequential" is not really the most correct term, but it's the name chosen by Keras developers. All models work in sequence, of course.

### The difference is:

- The `Sequential` model is a straight line. You keep adding layers, every new layer takes the output of the previous layer. You cannot make creative graphs with branches.
- The functoinal API `Model` is completely free to have as many ramifications, inputs and outputs as you need.

### Example with the `Sequential` model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential 
from keras.layers import *

#you create a model
model = Sequential()

#and you add layers
model.add(SomeKerasLayer(...))
model.add(AnotherKerasLayer(...))

#as you can see, this model is a straight line, you only add layers "sequentially"
```

### Example with the functional API `Model`:

Now here we start creating really fancy models.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import *
```

We start by defining input tensors. And we can have any number of inputs! (The sequential model is limited to one input, that you define in the first layer with `input_shape`).

```
input1 = Input(inputShape1)

#We can have more inputs if we want!
input2 = Input(inputShape2)
input3 = Input(inputShape3)
```

We work by creating layers and "calling layers with input tensors".
When we call a layer with an input tensor, we get an output tensor.
And we can create whatever path we want.

```
#Example: two separate layers taking two separate inputs:
output1 = SomeLayer(...)(input1)
output2 = AnotherLayer(...)(input2)
```

We can join two branches with different options, such as add, multiply, concatenate, etc.:

```
#joining the previous tensors output1 and output2
joined1_2 = Concatenate()([output1,output2])
```

We can reuse the same layers with different inputs, getting different outputs:

```
aLayer = AKerasLayer(...) #notice I'm creating this layer but not calling it yet

#calling the same layer with two different inputs
output1 = aLayer(joined1_2)
output2 = aLayer(input3)
```

And finally, we can define the model with as many inputs and outputs we want:

```
model = Model([input1,input2,input3],[output1, output2])
```

---

### Reusing and associating models

Both models, Sequential and functional API, can be used as if they were layers.

You can call a model with and input tensor and get an output tensor, just like you would do when creating a functional API model:

```
input1 = Input(shape)
output1 = anExistingSequentialModel(input1)
output2 = anExistingFunctionalModel(input1)

newModel = Model(input1,[output1,output2])
```

And you can add models in sequential models as well (beware of the branches, it's best to have one input and one output for the added model, since this is a Sequential one)

```
seqModel = Sequential()
seqModel.add(anotherModel)
```

Comment: "Well, "sequential" is not really the most correct term" - agreed, probably would need a more adequate name though...